# Abandon procedure, or clear procedure variable?

Tags: session, session-variables

I was wondering whether it was better procedure to abandon a session

e.g. `session.Abandon();`

or to clear the session variable data

`e.g. Session["PersonID"] = null;`

or would this be dependent on the situation?